# Creating tables for database

Tags: database-design

I want to design some tables for a database,but I have a problem.
I have a table for drivers and a table for cars,and 2 drivers may work on the same car.With due attention to terms,can you help me to design a table for my drivers and my cars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can a driver only ever work on one car for as long as your records are relevant? Then you have a one-to-many relationship between cars and drivers, and should represent this by giving drivers a car_id foreign key.

Can a driver work on multiple cars, while a car may be worked on by multiple drivers? Then you have a many-to-many relationship, and will need a junction table containing car_id and driver_id foreign keys to represent it.